# jquery custom validation rule

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

In my form I used the custom validation rule for date format

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "usDate",
        function(value, element) {
            // date mm/dd/yyyy
            return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);

        }
);
```

In validator i called as

```
phone : {
                usDate: true
        },
```

This is working fine. I need to modify this as this rule is called only if the phone field has filled by something. If this filed is blank then no need to validate this field.

And `value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/)` is working for 25/80/1212 ...

But the month is 1 to 12  and date is 1 to 31 ...

How to change this code. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "usDate",
        function(value, element) {
            // date mm/dd/yyyy
            return value.match(/^(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[\/](0[0-1]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[\/]\d{4}$/);

        }
);
```

In Validator you called as

```
phone : {
                required: true,
                usDate: true
        },
```